# how to I can fix : CORS multiple origin not allowed error in Axios

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, api, axios

I want to set a get request in Axios and get some data but I give this error: **CORS multiple origin not allowed**

my backend is WordPress API

this is my response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 29 Mar 2023 10:48:56 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
Link: <https://devapi.markazeahan.com/rest/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages, Link, Link
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-WP-Nonce, Content-Disposition, Content-MD5, Content-Type
Allow: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Wed, 29 Mar 2023 10:48:55 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Answer (score 0):

after many searches I understand my problem is this :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

It was set twice **origin** in my application

I solved my problem by entering this command in the function.php

```
function my_customize_rest_cors() {
    remove_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', 'rest_send_cors_headers' );
    add_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', function( $value ) {
        header_remove( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Link', false );

        return $value;
    } );
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'my_customize_rest_cors', 15 );
```